# Add Item from Dropdownlist to ListBox using JQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

How can i add anything user selected from dropdownlist to listbox using JQuery? and when i post the page i should be able to retrieve **"id, name"** from the listbox.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPerson" DataSourceID="ods_person" 
                DataValueField="Id" DataTextField="Name" runat="server" Width="221px" /><br />

                <asp:ListBox ID="lstPerson" runat="server" Width="245px"  
                Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Green" SelectionMode="Multiple">
                </asp:ListBox> <br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the items to the dropdown you can use the following script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function ()
    {
        $('[id$=items]').change(function (e)
        {
            var option = $('<option/>').html($(e.currentTarget).val());
            $('[id$=listBox]').append(option);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**BUT** you will run into an issue.  Items added to listbox will not be persisted back into the list box's "Items" on the server.  You will need to add these values into a hidden field on the client and split up the values on the server.

Comment: i see the problem but also i see the problem of  removing the items, i have a situation where the user can "Add" or "Remove" from from the listbox. is there any better way or should i use ajax updatepanel ? ;)

Comment: I'm sure there are a bunch of jquery plugins that do this as it is a very common UI feature.  Check out the jquery plugins site @ http://plugins.jquery.com/

Comment: its more pain than i thought... there should be a way... what plugin you want me to look for?

Answer (score 0):

When your asp.net dropdown list control renders, it will not look the same.  You need to run the page first to see what id to select it by.  Then use the $("#ddlPerson...").val() and .text() methods to access the data.

Comment: for dropdownlist i get - ctl00$cphMaster$ddlPerson

Comment: for listbox i get  - ctl00_cphMaster_lstPerson

Comment: This should do the trick.  



   $("#ctl00$cphMaster$ddlPerson").change(function () {
                var newOption = new Option($(this).text(), $(this).text());
                $("#ctl00_cphMaster_lstPerson").append(newOption);
            });